# Display array value to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uiview, nsarray

Im storing some values in my server. Then i fetched that values using JSON and added to local database table. Then i need to display that values to view. But array values displaying in NSLog. It won't displaying in view. I don't need to display in TableView.

code:

```
-(void) addDataToArray{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", documentsDirectory);

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);

    mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories order by order_by";

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";

        NSLog(@"Sql is %s",sql);


        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        int catID = 0;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


              NSString *catName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSLog(@"catName is %@",catName);

                [mArray addObject:catName];

                // [self.view addConstraints:mArray];

                NSLog(@"mArray is %@", mArray);

                [catName release];

                catID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);


            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
    }
}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
[self addDataToArray];
}
```

NSLog:

```
catName is person1
mArray is (
    person1
)

catName is person2

mArray is (
    person1
    person2
)
```

TextView:

```
    UITextView *txt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
      //  txt.text=[mArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:txt];

for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) { NSLog(@"index %d",i); }
```

Comment: Where do you want to show `JSON` data ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I need to show mArray value to TextView while button click.

Comment: You need to merge all objects of array first because you can show Only `NSString` in `UITextView`.

Comment: NSlog(@"%@",[mArray objectAtIndex:0]);just print what you getting?

Comment: UITextView *txt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
    txt.text=[mArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:txt];where these code calling? in viewDidload?

Comment: @iAppDeveloper: The values are displaying. But it display one value. How to display all value..Can you check my edited code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge `array's` objects to convert them in `string`, because you can't show an `array` in `textView` directly. If `mArray` contains `NSString` type object then you can do like this:

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (id obj in mArray){
    [string appendString:obj];
}

textView.text = string;
```

If you want to show each `person` in next line you can add `\n` after each name.

Comment: How to display all values using for loop. Im using below code. for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {
        NSLog(@"index %d",i);  }

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) { NSLog(@"index %@", mArray[i]); }`